# How to run repo from a script inside a container in a jenkins job

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cloudbees, repo

I am unable to run repo non-interactively inside a container as part of a freestyle job.

It prompts for the user-name and email. I got round that by doing a `git config --global` inside the job.

But then it does the color test, and that hangs indefinitely.

Looking at the source code for repo I see this

```
if os.isatty(0) and os.isatty(1) and not self.manifest.IsMirror:
      if opt.config_name or self._ShouldConfigureUser():
        self._ConfigureUser()
      self._ConfigureColor()
```

So, I ran the following inside the container:

```
python -C "import os; print os.isatty(0), os.isatty(1)"
```

and, sure enough, it printed out `True True`

Looking at the Jenkins log, it launches the container with `--tty` specified, and there seems no way to configure that option.

I can't find a `bash` option to force a script to be run in a non-interactive shell. If I put the above python line in a file and execute it with almost any combination of commands and options, it still prints out `True True`

The *only* way I see something different is if I use I/O redirection

```
bash <a.sh
```

which prints out `False True` - i.e. `stdin` is not a tty, and

```
bash <a.sh >a.log
```

which prints `False False`.

For a complex script, are there any problems using the `bash <script` approach?

Does anyone know any jenkins magic to prevent docker being launched using `--tty`?

I know that the `--tty` is the culprit. I built the container locally and ran the following

```
$ docker run repotest python -c "import os;print os.isatty(0), os.isatty(1)"
False False
$ docker run --tty repotest python -c "import os;print os.isatty(0), os.isatty(1)"
True True
```

Running Versions:

- repo: 1.12.37 (per Ubuntu 16.04 apt-get)
- Jenkins: 2.149
- Cloudbees Docker Plugin: 1.7.3
- Container base is ubuntu:xenial

I'm using the "Build inside a docker container" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run bash script `repo_script.sh` "non-interactively", or more exactly speaking without having terminals associated with standard streams, you could run your script simply as

```
 repo_script.sh < /dev/null 2>&1 | cat
```

assuming you want to see the output the way you would see it running simply as `repo_script.sh`. By piping the standard output and error to a different process the file descriptor appears as a pipe and not TTY to `repo_script.sh`. You could also direct output to a file, or even to `/dev/null` if you do not care about the output:

```
 log_file=/dev/null
 repo_script.sh < /dev/null > "${log_file}" 2>&1
```

Running the script as

```
 bash < repo_script.sh | cat
```

might would work too, though it is very unorthodox and to my mind hackish way of running a script just to break the association of TTY to the standard input. From script engine point of view, it is different to read a script program from a file than from standard input (which typically, if it is a terminal, is not seekable), so there might be some subtle differences that *could* possibly bite you in unexpected ways. This way does not as clearly communicate your intention to the next person that need to understand your code, and may lead to partial hair loss in that person due to extraneous head scratching.

There is no need for any bash options, just using the output directions from within the interpreting shell as above described is an easy-to-comprehend, multi-platform compatible standard convention for changing the standard stream associations.

P.S. I think it should be enough for your repo script to just test if the standard input is a TTY. It looks to me like the author of that script did not think deeply enough there. There is simply no use waiting for input if you do not have terminal device associated with standard input, and you could determine that everything needs to run without user interaction from there or stop with an error if that is not possible.

Comment: Thanks, worked a treat. But I would argue that `bash --non-interactive myscript` is a lot easier to comprehend than `myscript </dev/null | cat` :)  Idioms are only obvious when you already know them

Comment: Even MS-DOS and CP/M had output redirection, it is a conception from early 1970s, and can be explained fully in 10 lines of text. The option you propose is completely redundant.

Comment: Besides, shell scripts and other command line programs or even programs you write yourself are very often alredy "non-interactive" even if you do not change the standard stream associations. There is also other ways a program can interact than by standard input/output.

Comment: The output redirection is done by the shell before you exec the program/script. So by sticking to this half a century old standard convention, you are freely given the proposed functionality without needing to code it inside each of your applications or script engines (including `bash`). It is much simpler for programmers who want to write new programs; it is also much easier to users of those programs because they do not need to remember which option they need to use for each program and wonder does it even have such an option.

Comment: Also scripts are typically run without needing to specify or even know which script engine they should be run with because they include shebang [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)]. You would need to have seprate versions of scripts for "non-interactive" and "interactive" use cases. Lots of additional trouble for no gain.

Comment: Trying to avoid a quora like discussion here. My problem was down to trying to get  tools from many different vendors (jenkins, Docker, cloudbees, Google, the person who created the Jenkins job, and the actual script author) to work together. The only thing I could change was the Jenkins shell step.  I understand redirection (actually used CP/M and even earlier OS's) and can see how this achieves the desired effect. But you generally know if a script (or any program) will be non-interactive whe you write it. The "--non-interactive" switch could easily be specified in the shebang.

Comment: But it really *is* a hack. Using a side effect of redirection to control a characteristic of the execution environment, rather than it being part of the explicit contract within the script itself. From the Zen of Python, "Explicit is better than implicit"